# Mat Paginator Background Colour Change Via Css

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, paginator

Help Please, Mat Paginator Background is Not Changing, I want it to be transparent and I used the Below Code

```
::ng-deep .mat-paginator {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would it be possible to place your code into an editable snippet in order for the community to diagnose?

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there, in this case, you don't need to use ::ng-deep, which is being deprecated.

The reason why it's not working is that this code is expecting a class called mat-paginator and not a tag. So, remove the '.' (dot) in front of your mat-paginator and it will work.

YOUR CSS:

```
mat-paginator {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

[Example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/transparent-mat-paginator?file=src/app/paginator-configurable-example.css)

Comment: Hi thanks for the Help, But I'm Still not able to Get it transparent, any other Method to do this I'm Missing, Thanks

Comment: Well, did you check the example working on stackblitz? I don't know maybe there's something overwriting your css file, can you post a example on stackblitz of your project?

Comment: Hey Yeah I Checked the Stackblitz example, I did it in the same Way but still Able to see the Background Colour.

Answer (score 0):

Try RGBA. I'm using this right now and it's working for me (though I am using transparency but with a certain color). So, you could try something like this:

```
mat-paginator {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
```

And if it works, then this could work as well:

```
mat-paginator {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .0);
}
```

My point is, if 100% transparency doesn't work (second example here), then try partial transparency (.1, .5, etc).